# Design pattern for JNI pointer dependencies

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I'm creating Java wrappers for some C code using JNI. There are dependencies on the C side that look like this:

```
a = make_a();
b = make_b(a);
```

On the Java side I use `class A` and `class B` to hold references to the output of `make_a()` and `make_b`, along with various operations. Further, `class B` depends `class A` sticking around.

How can I create a dependency between the two classes from within JNI?

***Update***

I need class A to not be GC'd while class B is in use, and I need to create this dependency from within JNI.

Comment: So you want class B to be able to hold a pointer to class A?  I'm not entirely sure what you are getting at, but you can pass a pointer from a C/C++ structure to Java and then back again.

Comment: I need class A to not be GC'd while class B is in use, and I need to create this dependency from within JNI.

Comment: Can't you add to the Java interface (at the point right before it drops into JNI) so calls to make_b(a) will return an instance of B that contains a reference to the passed in A instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is NewGlobalRef/DeleteGlobalRef.  This will let your JNI hang on to an object reference.  Be careful-- this is an easy way to create memory leaks as its up to you to delete the reference!

Here are some links to get you going:

- [What is 'JNI Global reference'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112603/what-is-jni-global-reference)
- [Local and Global References](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/refs.html)
- [JNI Functions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html)