# jstack: what does "JNI global references" mean?

Tags: java, debugging, jstack

When running the `jstack` tool, the last line, after all the stack traces, is an output like this:

```
JNI global references: 1319
```

The question [What is 'JNI Global reference'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112603/what-is-jni-global-reference) 
explains what a "JNI Global reference" is, but I don't understand the significance of this value for the output of jstack.

So: What does the number mean, and why is it relevant for the output of jstack?

Answer (score 0):

I guess after read so articles:
1.the number is the count of references
2.jstack is viewing the jvm,the jni level of jvm has a limit of references of global.