# Crash in android when using android context in CPP layer

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x-2.x

I am using NDK with cocos2dx.  In main.cpp, I have the following method.

```
       void Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeInit(JNIEnv*  env, 
           jobject thiz, jint w, jint h)
```

Is it possible to assign              jobject thiz                 to another object and use in cpp? Just like this:-

```
         static jobject context = NULL;
         void Manager::SetJobject(jobject object)
         {
           context = object;
         }
          .............
         // in some other class
         //if platform == ANDROID
           connectToSomeThirdParty(context, key );
```

I tried this , but I got crash. Crash log is shown below:

```
10-01 11:38:13.228: E/dalvikvm(5828): JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale local reference 0x1e200001
10-01 11:38:13.228: E/dalvikvm(5828): VM aborting
10-01 11:38:13.228: A/libc(5828): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000016c4 (code=-6), thread 5857 (Thread-577)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try global references. Please see:

[Global and Local References (Oracle about JNI)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#global_local)

[What is 'JNI Global reference'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112603/what-is-jni-global-reference) (at StackOverflow)

"A JNI global reference is a reference from "native" code to a Java object managed by the Java garbage collector."
"JNI global references are prone to memory leaks."

It is more or less safe to store the application context, storing a reference to an Activity during initialization [is almost definitely a memory leak](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) (normally after a screen turn a new Activity is created and the old one is garbage-collected).
If you do not really want to care about freeing the resources, consider a
refactoring like:

```
class MyClass {
    static Context mContext;
    MyClass(Context c) {
        mContext = c.getApplicationContext(); // or just c
    }
    public static myFunc(int arg) {
        myFuncNative(mContext, arg);
    }
    private static native myFuncNative(Context c, int a);
}
```

It is still recommended to keep the application context.

People do use references to activities, but usually such references are set in *onResume()* and cleared in *onPause()*.